# TypeError: this[(("_" + (intermediate value)) + "_listener")] is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm dynamically building an object that will have a sender on it:

```
var coins = {};

['USD','EUR'].forEach((product_id) => {
    coins[`_${product_id}`] = {};
    coins[`_${product_id}_listener`] = (val) => {
        log.info(process.pid, 'terminal send', product_id, [`_${product_id}`]);
        terminal.send({
            action: product_id,
            data: this[`_${product_id}`],
            timestamp: new Date,
        });
    };

    Object.defineProperty(coins, product_id, {
        set: (val) => {
            this[`_${product_id}`] = val;
            this[`_${product_id}_listener`](val);
        },
        get: (val) => {
            return this[`_${product_id}`];
        },
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, when I set a coin to something ...

```
coins['USD'] = {a: 4};
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: this[(("_" + (intermediate value)) + "_listener")] is not a function
at Object.set (repl:15:32)
at repl:1:18
at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:73:12)
at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:340:29)
at bound (domain.js:280:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:538:10)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
```

This is obviously referring to the second line of the setter, but I'm not sure why. If I comment that out, gets and sets work fine. My listener just doesn't fire ... obviously. The goal here is to get the listener to fire.

## Follow up

I've also noticed, with that line commented out, that the object doesn't look *right* (imo):

```
> coins['USD'] = {a: 4};
{ a: 4 }
> coins
{ _USD: {},
  _USD_listener: [Function],
  _EUR: {},
  _EUR_listener: [Function] }
> coins['_USD']
{}
> coins['USD']
{ a: 4 }
```

Since my setter is *supposively* setting `_USD`, why doesn't `_USD` look set when I print out `coins`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that arrow functions unlike normal function does not allow to change context (`this`). [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own **this**, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for **non-method functions**

So when you create an arrow function context will be captured once an for all calls.

You could iether switch to normal functions or create arrow functions using `coins` as a context. For example by passing `coins` as a context to `.forEach` call and replacing iteratee with a normal function to allow dynamic context.

```js
var coins = {};

['USD','EUR'].forEach(function(product_id) {
    this[`_${product_id}`] = {};
    this[`_${product_id}_listener`] = (val) => {
        console.log(`${product_id} - ${val}`)
    };

    Object.defineProperty(coins, product_id, {
        set: (val) => {
            this[`_${product_id}`] = val;
            this[`_${product_id}_listener`](val);
        },
        get: (val) => {
            return this[`_${product_id}`];
        },
    });
}, coins)

coins.USD = 10
coins.EUR = 100
console.log(`USD ${coins.USD}, EUR ${coins.EUR}`)
```

Or better use normal function because you do have "methods"

```js
    var coins = {};

    ['USD','EUR'].forEach(product_id => {
        coins[`_${product_id}`] = {};
        coins[`_${product_id}_listener`] = function(val) {
            console.log(`${product_id} - ${val}`)
        };

        Object.defineProperty(coins, product_id, {
            set: function(val) {
                this[`_${product_id}`] = val;
                this[`_${product_id}_listener`](val);
            },
            get: function() {
                return this[`_${product_id}`];
            },
        });
    })

    coins.USD = 10
    coins.EUR = 100
    console.log(`USD ${coins.USD}, EUR ${coins.EUR}`)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick and thorough answer! At first I thought it was late night coding causing the issue, but now that I'm awake again I'm still not sure how your second answer or [mozilla's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Defining_a_setter_on_existing_objects_using_defineProperty) works and mine doesn't. The `this[`_${product_id}`] = val` appears (to me) to be outside the context of the `function`. I thought it was a special pointer for the object, but I guess there's some inheritance that I'm not fully grasping.

Comment: @VertigoRay Consider the following example `const obj = {fn() { return this}, arrow: () => this}`. If you do `console.log(obj.fn(), obj.arrow())` you'll see different outputs because `obj.smth()` is equivalent to `obj.smth.call(obj)`. If `smth` is arrow function it won't affect it's context because it is set once and for all as if you did `bind` with normal function.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, replacing all of the `this` variables with `coins` will fix the issue. I'm still not 100% sure why it didn't work or if this is even the best solution.

```
var coins = {};

['USD','EUR'].forEach((product_id) => {
    coins[`_${product_id}`] = {};
    coins[`_${product_id}_listener`] = (val) => {
        log.info(process.pid, 'terminal send', product_id, [`_${product_id}`]);
        terminal.send({
            action: product_id,
            data: coins[`_${product_id}`],
            timestamp: new Date,
        });
    };

    Object.defineProperty(coins, product_id, {
        set: (val) => {
            coins[`_${product_id}`] = val;
            coins[`_${product_id}_listener`](val);
        },
        get: (val) => {
            return coins[`_${product_id}`];
        },
    });
});
```

I'd prefer  an answer provided by someone else ... or at least validation that this is the way it should be done. Thanks!